# Specifying Powershell version in Shortcut Target not working

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

I have two Windows Server 2012 R2 64bit Setup identially and have SharePoint 2010 Management Shell shortcut links pinned to my task bar.  Both the shortcuts specify -Version 2 but only one server seems to honor that flag.  Why is on server not honoring the version 2 flag?

On one server the Target property of the Short is:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe -Version 2 -NoExit  " & ' C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\CONFIG\POWERSHELL\Registration\\sharepoint.ps1 ' "
```

When PowerShell opens get-host returns version 2.0 as expected.

```
Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 2.0
InstanceId       : b0c653b6-8951-46c9-a5a6-00fe49d70e79
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserI
                   nterface
CurrentCulture   : en-US
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost+ConsoleColorProxy
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace
```

On the other server, however the link is also:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe -Version 2 -NoExit  " & ' C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\CONFIG\POWERSHELL\Registration\\sharepoint.ps1 ' "
```

But get-host returns this:

```
Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 4.0
InstanceId       : 1a9413a0-cdbb-46a3-bbe3-b3dbc72fad38
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : en-US
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost+ConsoleColorProxy
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have PS V2 enabled on your second server. Its not enabled by default in Win2012R2. can you run `Get-WindowsFeature PowerShell-V2`and see if it is enabled?

Comment: seems so: 
[X] Windows PowerShell 2.0 Engine                   PowerShell-V2                  Installed

Comment: are you able to manually launch PS in V2? launch "powershell -version 2.0" from cmd.. and check $psversiontable

Comment: tried that.  the odd thing is that if I run from a batch file with the following command then it works.  powershell -version 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to:

C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0 there is a powershell.exe.config

Remove the   `<supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/>`  line and leave the file like this:

```
<configuration> 
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/> 
    </startup> 
</configuration>
```

Do this if you have checked DB permissions to have Shell access

Comment: i think we can keep both versions